# AWS CodePipeline + CodeDeploy + CodeCommit with --file-exists-behavior option

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-deployment, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I have a CD work flow using CodePipeline + CodeCommit + CodeDeploy to EC2 instances.

I have everything else working except for this --file-exists-behavior option. If I create a deployment from the Aws CLI or the console. The deployment works fine.

Is there anyway I can use this option with CodePipeline?

I am still getting an error without this option.

`The deployment failed because a specified file already exists at this location`

Comment: Similar solution discussed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590332/aws-codedeploy-fail-the-deployment-failed-because-a-specified-file-already-exis

Comment: Hi, Kannaiyan, i ve read that question, but it doesnt involve codePipeline.

Answer (score 1):

So, when you deploy, CodeDeploy will look for a file (on the instance) with information on previously deployed files for the application/deployment-group in question, if it finds the file it then it uses it to cleanup (delete) the existing files, preparing for copying of the new revision files.

[Refer This AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployment-steps.html#deployment-rollback)

But if the cleanup file doesn't exist, either because the existing code was initially deployed in some other way (eg cloudformation instance userdata/metadata sources) or the CodeDeploy deployment-group has been recreated for some reason then the cleanup file will either not exist or not match the deployment-group id. Therefore it wont be run. Therefore the files will not be cleaned up, and the deployment will fail since CodeDeploy does not overwrite files.

What a Solution could be in this scenario *is to have a hook (eg BeforeInstall) that calls a script to delete the applications files (if they exist) on the instance.*

Hope this helps

Comment: Does it mean, if I deploy the files once with CLI or console once, I dont have to worry about --file-exists-behavior option?

Comment: Nope that was for CLI you would still need an script for before install to remove existing file