# CodeDeploy configuration to overwrite files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I am deploying via `CodeDeploy` a logstash configuration in a target instance in `/etc/logstash/`.

This is the last step in a 3-staged `CodePipeline`.

However it fails with message

> The deployment failed because a specified file already exists at this location: /etc/logstash/pipelines.yml

How can I instruct `CodeDeploy` to overwrite files?

Comment: as my answer gets deleted because "it's not tailored", although i feel it is, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590332/aws-codedeploy-fail-the-deployment-failed-because-a-specified-file-already-exis/44761130#44761130.

Answer (score 6):

March 2022 Update: Here are the docs on how to handle the file-exists-behavior: [AppSpec 'files' Section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-files.html).

July 2021 Update: Looks like AWS has finally acknowledged this defect -- look [here for updates](https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/14) on all that.

August 2020 answer:
The only way I have seen that you can overwrite files is selecting to overwrite or retain, [as seen here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-rollback-and-redeploy.html), when you're **creating a new deployment**. In no other place will you see those settings. And if I'm not mistaken, this is the only way to do it because it is not supported on the CLI.

Comment: It might be helpful to people to add a link to the docs with the new option: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-files.html

Comment: It might also be helpful to re-order this answer to lead with the current solution.

Answer (score 0):

An issue to add an overwrite option is open on [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/14)  and it has been there for quite a while. I solved this by adding a custom script in the BeforeInstallation hook which will erase all existing files before copying over my new deployment.

This is how my appspec.yml file looks like

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /path/to/destination
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: DeploymentScripts/CleanupScript.sh
  AfterInstall:
    - location: DeploymentScripts/InstallScript.sh
      timeout: 600
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: DeploymentScripts/RestartScript.sh
      timeout: 3600
```

Comment: This is already possible, but you have to initiate this in the command of the executing codedeploy. You can find more information

docs.aws.amazon.com (strangely under 'rollback')

cli docs.aws.amazon.com (see --file-exists-behavior (string))

Comment: I found the `overwrite: true` setting in the `files:` section did not help.  As mentioned, add some script commands to remove the files in the `BeforeInstall` hook.  For example:
`cd /path/to/app
rm -rf *`

Answer (score -2):

You can pass this attribute in the appspec.yml under

files :
      overwrite: true

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/14) tells us that your solution is not currently supported.